# How write formula on Polish TIN (taxpayer identification number) using that like Validation rule

Tags: formula, validation-rule, admin

Who knows how best to approach this task. I was asked to add a TIN field to Account. This is the Polish taxpayer number for the firm. This field should be checked to be sure that the user entered it correctly. At the bottom under the text I leave a screenshot according to which rule this number is checked.
[image: Rule]
Is it possible to do something like this using Validation rule and the formulas it contains?

I've achieved something. I wrote a formula that would check the TIN. In my opinion, it should look like below in the insert with the code.

```
MOD(
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 0, 1)) * 6) +
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 1, 1)) * 5) + 
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 2, 1)) * 7) + 
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 3, 1)) * 2) + 
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 4, 1)) * 3) + 
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 5, 1)) * 4) + 
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 6, 1)) * 5) + 
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 7, 1)) * 6) + 
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 8, 1)) * 7),
11)  > 10
```

But for some reason a record returns to me with an error of the following content:  Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

I would be very grateful if someone would rate my formula and tell me if it is well written in general and where I need to put the parentheses. Because I have already run out of all possible options for how to put them.

Thank you for checking the original formula and for the explanations related to the placement of brackets. I've moved on. But my ValidationRule does not work as it should. This is what my formula looks like now.

```
MOD(
VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 0, 1))) * 6 +
VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 1, 1))) * 5 + 
VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 2, 1))) * 7 + 
VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 3, 1))) * 2 + 
VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 4, 1))) * 3 + 
VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 5, 1))) * 4 + 
VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 6, 1))) * 5 + 
VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 7, 1))) * 6 + 
VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 8, 1))) * 7,
11)     =    10
 && 
MOD(
VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 0, 1))) * 6 +
VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 1, 1))) * 5 + 
VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 2, 1))) * 7 + 
VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 3, 1))) * 2 + 
VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 4, 1))) * 3 + 
VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 5, 1))) * 4 + 
VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 6, 1))) * 5 + 
VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 7, 1))) * 6 + 
VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 8, 1))) * 7,
11)      <>      VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 9, 1))
```

It should check whether the entered TIN is correct. The first task
[image]
The next task. This is so that the second part of the formula checks that the last digit with TIN is equal to MOD 11. As in the screenshot below.

[image]

But in my case it looks like I can enter all the numbers and ValidationRule will accept everything. Unless it's just 9999999999

Who could help me at this stage of the Validation Rule build? Because at this stage everything has somehow changed places. ValidationRule accepts everything, there are no syntactic or any other errors, but I'm still not happy with the result. I've reached a dead end and now I don't know what to do with it all.

Comment: Yes, it is possible in a validation rule (using `VALUE()`, `MID()`, `MOD()` from [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5)). This would be easier in Apex though. Beyond that, what have you tried? where are you stuck?

Comment: In general, I'm just starting my adventure with Salesforce. At this moment, I am studying on the Trailhead platform. Passed all the main levels associated with the Admin. But there were simple tasks and they could be done with a few lines of formulas. And I don't even know how to approach this task. I have basic admin knowledge. And here I wanted to ask the experts where would I even start?

Comment: 1/2: Being able to break a problem down into smaller parts is important, and you'll need to practice to become good at it. You'll probably get more out of this exercise with small pushes in the right direction, and this site shines when you can say "this is what I'm trying to do, this is what I've tried, this is where I'm stuck". So the small push I'll offer for now is _you first need to get individual characters from your starting string, and convert them to numbers_. Look through the documentation I linked and at the functions I mentioned to see which might help you do that.

Comment: 2/2: Start by trying to get the first character, then get the first and second (separately) and try to add them together. I will say that the formula you will end up with (when you extract all 10 characters) will look like it has a lot of repetition in it. That's the price we pay to do things declaratively instead of "with code" (although I'd argue that formulas and flows aren't too terribly far removed from writing code). If you can get to the point where you can extract the first 9 chars and add them, the rest should be fairly simple. If you can't, then a less complex exercise would be good.

Comment: Okay, I understand you. When I broke the task into smaller components. I have a question. How do I make it so that I can call this variable? I mean, how do I make the first digit be taken from the string TIN and multiplied by 6?

Comment: We don't have variables in formulas (which is why formulas tend to have a lot of repetition). It's just a long chain of function calls. You directly feed one result into another function (or operator) until you get what you want. As an example, taking the day portion of today, and multiplying that by 2 would be `DAY(TODAY()) * 2`. If you need to work on both the month and the day of today, you just need to call `TODAY()` a second time `( DAY(TODAY()) * 2 ) + ( MONTH(TODAY()) * 3 )`. You should now have enough information to [edit] your question to show us an attempt (even if it doesn't work).

Comment: What do think about that?

Comment: I already have some progress. But I would still need the help of experts. Because the formula doesn't work the way it should. I would be very grateful if you could see what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at your formula and try to spot where you might have an error by minimizing it:

```
MOD(
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 0, 1)) * 6) +
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 1, 1)) * 5) + 
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 2, 1)) * 7) + 
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 3, 1)) * 2) + 
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 4, 1)) * 3) + 
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 5, 1)) * 4) + 
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 6, 1)) * 5) + 
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 7, 1)) * 6) + 
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 8, 1)) * 7),
11)  > 10
```

Here we can see that first and last lines are just the parenthesis/brackets for the `MOD` function, so if you ignore whatever is in the middle, you will get:

```
MOD(X, 11) >10
```

Which looks good. Then the error is not there. Let's look inside the first element of your MOD function:

all lines are generally the same, so let's review only 1 of them in more detail:

```
(VALUE((MID( NIP__c , 0, 1)) * 6)
```

Here we have this in the middle:

```
MID( NIP__c , 0, 1)
```

Which is good, so let's call it X for now. Then we have:

```
(VALUE((X) * 6)
```

We can remove the brackets from around X, so the result is:

```
(VALUE(X * 6)
```

So you see that we have an unclosed opening bracket. The solution would be to remove that opening bracket on each line

Answer (score 1):

In its current state, I think the only thing you need to get your validation rule working is to change the `&&` (the "AND" operator) to `||` (the "OR" operator).

Validation rules prevent records from being saved when the overall result is `true`.  This is kinda non-intuitive (at least for me, a programmer), and I find it helps to think of them as actually being *invalidation* rules. The goal here is to describe when your data is *invalid*.

If you aren't familiar with Boolean logic,
`AND` returns true only when all of the things being "and"ed together are true.  (e.g. `true && true && true == true`)
`OR` returns true if any of the things being "or"d together are true. (e.g. `false || false || true == true`)

When you're using `AND`, you're saying that both the `mod(<sum>, 11)` needs to be 10 *and* the check digit needs to not match. In reality, either of those conditions being true mean that the TIN is invalid.

Another fundamental bit of Boolean logic is DeMorgan's Law. Applying a `!` (the "NOT" operator, which flips true and false, so `!false == true` and `!true == false`) to something containing "AND" and/or "OR" also flips the "AND"/"OR" operators.

All of that is to say that if `A` is "mod(sum, 11) != 10", and `B` is "mod(sum, 11) == check digit", then
`!(A && B)` and
`!A || !B`
are equivalent

So you're looking for "mod(sum, 11) == 10 OR mod(sum, 11) != check digit"

```
MOD(
    VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 0, 1)) * 6 +
    VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 1, 1)) * 5 + 
    VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 2, 1)) * 7 + 
    VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 3, 1)) * 2 + 
    VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 4, 1)) * 3 + 
    VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 5, 1)) * 4 + 
    VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 6, 1)) * 5 + 
    VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 7, 1)) * 6 + 
    VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 8, 1)) * 7,
    11
) = 10
|| 
MOD(
    VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 0, 1)) * 6 +
    VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 1, 1)) * 5 + 
    VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 2, 1)) * 7 + 
    VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 3, 1)) * 2 + 
    VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 4, 1)) * 3 + 
    VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 5, 1)) * 4 + 
    VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 6, 1)) * 5 + 
    VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 7, 1)) * 6 + 
    VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 8, 1)) * 7,
    11
) <> VALUE(MID( NIP__c , 9, 1))
```

+bonus:
for a little bit of fun, since I mentioned it would be easier to do this in code, here's what the code could look like

```java
public Boolean validateTIN(String tin){
    List<Integer> multipliers = new List<Integer>{6, 5, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    Integer checkDigit = Integer.valueOf(tin.right(1));
    Integer mod11Sum = 0;

    for(Integer i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        mod11Sum += Integer.valueOf(tin.mid(i, 1)) * multipliers[i];
    }

    mod11Sum = Math.mod(mod11Sum, 11);
    return (mod11Sum != 10 && mod11Sum == checkDigit);
    // The inverse would also work
    //return !(mod11Sum == 10 || mod11Sum != checkDigit);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Derek! Thank you very much for explaining how the logic works in Validation Rules. I tried the version of the formula that was offered to me. I corrected my formula and wrote everything down. But unfortunately when I tried to enter the NIP or TIN number in the field. Validation Rules did not accept it.  But when I enter something in the style of 9999999999. Which does not exist in nature or in tax legislation. So I don't even know what to do in this case. Maybe I will retrain more in salesforce developers. Here, how would the code look better.